# Tag synonym request Apache to Apache2

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Since we did the work to rid ourselves of [apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apache) we have had to 'clean it out' on at least 5 occasions as it keeps getting recreated.

Please synonym [apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apache) to [apache2](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apache2)

while we wait for it to be burninated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tags have been synonomized. Actually, they've been merged since that also transfers favorite/ignored status and any email notices that may be in effect.